# iOS Application with Flex UI

Tags: iphone, ios, apache-flex, air, uiapplicationdelegate

I am working on an application which UI is fully written in FLEX (tool Adobe Flash Builder 4.6) and fetching all updates from local sqlite database.Local sqlite database updates from server are processing in background using GCD.These background tasks are written in objective C and integrated with FLEX UI as a static library.Is there any way to use UIApplication Delegate protocol methods like didEnterBackground..etc., from this static library without using Appdelegate.h file?

Comment: I only half understand what you're asking, but I think the answer is the use Native Extensions w/ Adobe AIR to execute Native iOS Code.

Comment: @Reboog Exactly sir...I am creating a static library for all Background tasks from Xcode and use that library to create .ane(Air Native Extension)...Using flash builder 4.6 I am creating .ipa file.There is no Appdelgate.h in my static library but I like to use UIApplicationDelegate methods.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer.

If we build our application using FLEX then **its not possible to register** our application **with UIApplicationDelegate methods**.

Instead of trying in Objective C, I implemented these delegate methods in FLEX.

Its solved my problem.